# Solve Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation 
$$y^2y'^2+2axyy'+(1-a)y^2+ax^2+(a-1)b=0,$$ where $y=y(x)$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}.$

**My work**: Let $y^2=z, \,\,\,z=z(x).$ Then $2yy'=z'$ and our differential equation become 
$$\frac{z'^2}{4}+axz'+(1-a)z+ax^2+(a-1)b=0.$$

But, what now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
$$(yy'+ax)^2-a^2x^2+(1-a)y^2+ax^2+(a-1)b=0$$

$$(yy'+ax)^2+(1-a)(y^2+ax^2-b)=0$$
$P=y^2+ax^2$

Comment: That was nice. Thank you!